# Evaluating machine learning model with missing features

Tags: classification

I am working on a credit risk binary classification problem. The classes are GoodPayers and BadPayers.  The training set has variables/features that contains:

1. DemoGraphics Data  such as - Age, Education, Loan Amount, Interest Rate
2. Behavioral Data such as - Payment in Month1, Payment in Month2, Payment in Month3, Payment delay in Month1, Payment delay in Month2.

The 10-fold cross-validation has 0.82 AUC on this set.

However, the unseen data just contains the 'Demographics Data' and does not have 'Behavioral Data' of Payment.  How do we deploy/test the model based on DemoGraphics Dataset only?

Comment: Could you tell more about behavioral data? Would it be possible to train new models without these features? Are these features very related to your model performance?

Comment: @Theudbald [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html) shows that the behavioral data are significantly important for achieving the model performance. Without these, the ROC drops to 0.65.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If less than 20-25% of behavioral data is missing, maybe you could try to impute missing data  using one of the following solutions :

- Impute missing behavioral data using some business rule or by training a machine learning model with demographics data as input and behavioral data as output variable.
- Impute missing data with feature mean/median.
- Impute missing data by picking up random value in the feature distribution (hot-deck).

In case you have more than 20-25% missing data, it will be really hard to impute values. I think in this situation you should consider creating a new model such as :

- The new model doesn't use behavioral data anymore.
- The new model is based on a different train-val-test split in order to have behavioral data in each dataset.

If you can't create a new model neither impute missing data, I guess hot-deck would be the best option you have to avoid bad performance on unseen data.